# In which order R1, R2 and Akito the Exiled need to be watched?

Tags: code-geass, code-geass-akito-the-exiled

I am planing to watch *R1*, *R2* again with *Akito the Exiled* but will be joined by a person who have no idea about *Code Geass* before.

I know *Akito the Exiled* take place between R1 and R2 [from the similar question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6524/where-does-code-geass-boukoku-no-akito-fall-in-the-story-line) but I have no idea how much they are related to each other in details.

So what is the best order to watch *R1*, *R2* and *Akito the Exiled* without getting anything spoiled in advance?

Comment: AFAIK Akito the Exiled was not strictly related to the main story. I watched R1 > R2 and then watched Akito the Exiled as a side story. As @endyey mentioned, _You can watch r1 then r2 without getting spoiler in akito the exiled_ but I suppose you are wondering if watching Akito the Exiled after R1 would spoil R2 for you? I'm interested to know as well TBH. Perhaps someone who watched the series recently can shed some light into this?

Comment: Why not watch in release order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Story of R1 and R2 isn't affected by Akito the Exiled enough to be considered a spoiler of any sort.

AtE is an Alternate/Side-story and thus you can watch it whenever you want, though I'd advise to watch in the release order (and not just for Code-Geass, but almost every series out there) because that's how they are made and that's how you're supposed to be watching it.

Comment: There are many series where if you take an OVA and place it after the main series, you have no context as to how those characters are feeling at that time anymore. It will lose a lot of the impact. For Jobless Reincarnation, makes sense to do that after the series. For One Punch Man's OVAs and Re:Zero's Memory Snow, it's best to watch them in-between their respective episodes; otherwise, they won't have the same impact. They can also be story-relevant to later jokes.

Answer (score 3):

Start with R1 then R2 and later Exile of Akito.

In the code geass Universe, while Japan kept up some rebellions against Britannia, Europe was also in constant war with them. 
Exile of Akito is all about the wars in Europe, and in the time period between R1 and R2.

Answer (score 0):

Chronologically Akito the Exiled takes place between season 1 and 2, but it's better to first finish season 2 before watching Akito because you don't want to interrupt the flow of the story of the main series.

Comment: This is what I was thinking. If you're deep into Lelouch's storyline, why put another series in-between. Unless that series is plot relevant and will increase your view of the next season of the main series. It sounds like it doesn't do that?

Answer (score -1):

Watch R1, R2 then Akito of the Exiled. I think Akito of the Exiled was created for alternative story. You don't have to watch it. If you don't watch Akito of the Exiled nothing will change.